# What did I do wrong while debugging a python script mod for The Sims 4?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

I was trying to debug a modified python script for The Sims 4, running the mod's code in the game context and trying to access the variables using the pydevd-pycharm package and a python debug server, both provided by PyCharm Pro. Although I followed the necessary instructions and settings (described below), I was still unable to successfully debug.

The method I used to perform the debug attempt is as follows:

1. Inside the PyCharm Pro installation files (version 2022.3.2), I took a copy of the file “pydevd-pycharm.egg” and changed the extension of that file to “.zip” so that I could edit it;
2. Inside the python installation files (version 3.7.0), I made a copy of the “ctypes” directory and inserted it inside the “pydevd-pycharm.zip” file created in the previous step; this “.zip” file was inserted into the Mods directory, like any other mod;
3. I configured a python debug server in Pycharm Pro and created a command for The Sims 4 that contained the code to connect to the debug server. The command was as follows:

```
import sims4.commands


@sims4.commands.Command('start.debug', command_type=sims4.commands.CommandType.Live)
def startdebugging(_conection=None):
   import pydevd_pycharm
   pydevd_pycharm.settrace('localhost', port=5678, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

4. I also inserted the command as any mod in the Mods directory and started the python debug server (which was waiting for a connection); I minimized PyCharm Pro and started the game; already inside the game, I started the command start.debug; if everything had gone well, I would be debugging the mod script now.

(If you want to know more about the method I used, the tutorial link is: https://youtu.be/RBnS8m0174U)

In conclusion, i want to know why the method I ran ended up not working and, if possible, suggestions on how I can modify the debug method so that it finally works.